# Are proofs by contradiction and counterexample two different techniques?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

New to proofs.

Suppose I want to prove $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ as $f(n) = 2n$ for all $n$ is not onto. Are the two arguments below valid, *separate* proofs? Are they invalid iterations of a single proof?

By contradiction:

Suppose $f$ is onto. Then for all $m \in \mathbb Z$, there's some $k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $f(k) = 2k = m$ which implies $k = \frac m2.$ Then $k \not \in \mathbb Z$ for all $m \in \mathbb Z.$ Contradiction.

By counter-example:

$1$ has no pre-image in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: They are both valid.  In this case, you just need to find one integer that cannot be mapped to by the $f$ function.  Personally I would prefer that you be more specific in the first proof (i.e., "then $k \notin \mathbb{Z}$ if $m$ is odd, contradiction").  Similar for the second (explain why 1 has no pre-image).

Comment: Math is not as flexible as English. I assume by "$k\notin \mathbb Z$ for all $m\in \mathbb Z$" you meant that for some $m\in \mathbb Z$ we have that $k\notin \mathbb Z$. It's incorrect to write it that way. What you wrote is only true if $k$ is never an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first proof seems to be wrong. Why does $k \notin \mathbb Z$? Your second proof seems to be correct, although if someone seriously wants a proof of the non-surjectivity of $f$, perhaps they want more detail.

As for the difference between proofs by counterexample and proofs by contradiction: there is no way to answer this question *exactly* without making precise by what you mean by a proof by counterexample, and what you mean by "different techniques", but I interpret it as something like this:

Let $P$ be some property. You are asked to prove $\neg\forall x P(x)$. A proof by counterexample constructs some $c$, and then proves $\neg P(c)$, effectively proving $\exists x \neg P(x)$. A proof by contradiction assumes $\forall xP(x)$ and then derives a contradiction.

In classical mathematics, these results are easily seen to be equivalent. However, if we move to constructive mathematics, then in fact these two are *not* equivalent; it is possible that you are able to prove $\neg \forall x P(x)$ without being able to prove $\exists x\neg P(x)$. This suggests that (even in classical mathematics) these are not *quite* the same proof technique, because by just slightly weakening what kind of argument we allow, the conclusion of one does not follow from the conclusion of the other.

Comment: I think that statement in the first proof "then $k \notin \mathbb{Z}$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$" is not intended to mean that there is no integer $m$ for which it is true, only that it is not true for _all_ integers $m$ (i.e., there are some integers $m$, namely odds, for which it fails).  I agree that statement could be clarified.

Comment: I understood this : $\exists m \in Z / k \notin Z$

Answer (score 0):

You first proof is not worded correctly.  The statement "$k \notin \mathbb{Z}$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$" is not true since there are some values of $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.   For the proof, you need to only exhibit one value of $m$ for which there does not exist a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $2k=m$.

One way to prove $p \Rightarrow q$ is to assume $p$ is true and $q$ is false and then arrive at a contradiction.  This argument is valid because $(p \wedge \neg q) \Rightarrow F$ is logically equivalent to $p \Rightarrow q$.  In the example given, the hypothesis is the definition of the function $f$ and the conclusion is that $f$ is not onto.  So we can assume the hypothesis is true and the conclusion is false and arrive at a contradiction.  Indeed, if $f$ is onto, then there exists an integer $k$ such that $2k=1$, which is impossible.

Both your proofs are essentially the same.